# how to store Json associative array to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have JSon data from a web service and I decoded it into associative array using

```
$data = json_decode($postdata, true);

using print_r($data);
```

---

Array

```
(
  [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [cityName] => London
            [cityState] => London
            [cityPopulation] => 8173194
            [country] => United Kingdom
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cityName] => Bombay
            [cityState] => Maharashtra
            [cityPopulation] => 12478447
            [country] => India
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cityName] => Kuala Lumpur
            [cityState] => Federal Territory
            [cityPopulation] => 1627172
            [country] => Malaysia
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [cityName] => New York
            [cityState] => New York
            [cityPopulation] => 8336697
            [country] => United States
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [cityName] => Berlin
            [cityState] => Berlin
            [cityPopulation] => 3538652
            [country] => Deutschland
        )

)
```

I would like to insert each of the id, cityName, cityName, cityState, cityPopulation, country for each four array into a existing mysql database..

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable "
         ."(id, cityName, cityState, citypopulation,country) "
         ."VALUES (:id, :cityName, :cityState, :cityPopulation, :country)");

foreach ($data as $entry){
    foreach ($entry as $column => $value){
      $query->bindParam(':' . $column, $value);
    }
    $query->execute($entry);
}
```

Or something of that nature...

Comment: I tried but I didn't work with me!

Comment: "Didn't work" is not specific enough.

Comment: Well doesnt show anything on the screen!

Comment: @MohammedDizayee: it shouldn't it will just silently insert the values in to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode it into a string. Look at messagePack (http://msgpack.org/). It is a really light weight encoding.

Comment: That's a good over-the-wire format, but not as good for serialization because it's binary and can't be copy-pasted or manipulated using conventional tools.